# Bug with jquery UI datepicker using only Months and Years

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I found piece of code below on SOF earlier today.

```
$("input[name=startDate], input[name=endDate]").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date("2008-09-01"), 
    maxDate: "+5Y",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    dateFormat: 'mm.yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    },
    beforeShow : function(input, inst) {
        if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
            year = datestr.substring(datestr.length-4, datestr.length);
            month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length-5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month));
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see I would like to use them on 2 different inputs to be able to search between 2 given months & years.

There is a problem when I click the same input 2nd time;

- Let's say I choose **10.2011**
- If I click 2nd time I can chose from **01.2010** to **12.2010**
- If I click 3rd time I can chose from **01.2009** to **12.2009**

This goes on till it hits **minDate** value (**2008**).

I will be really glad if you could help me out with fixing this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is the assignment to `month` inside `beforeShow`. It attempts to get the readable month names from datepicker, e.g. "July". But what it really wants is just the number representing the month. So, just change that line to:

```
  var month = datestr.substring(0, datestr.length-5) - 1;
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/william/GyP2u/.

Comment: It is working in jsfiddle.net but for some reason, if I change the year and try to select another year in same input, I can't select any other year because only option is the one I selected before. For example If I selected 2012 and later try to change the year to 2011, only option for the year is 2012. Again strangely if I go to another tab and come back (without refreshing the search page tab) I can choose different years again.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. What browser are you using? Do you use the jsfiddle I posted above?

Comment: Yes, I have. Strangely Mozilla is creating problem. I might have to try disabling some addons and giving a shot later. Thanks a lot for your help.